# GCM Ccs Server Implementation

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

This is more of a clarification question rather than a problem.

I have been making an android app for our Capstone project and we are stuck with this IM chat issue.

We went with the XMPP Ccs endpoint that GCM provides for upstream as well as downstream messaging.

The funny thing is that the library to achieve this is Smack by igniterealtime still maintained and the only library for Java.

The implementation that google provides in their website [GCM Ccs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) is for older version of Smack. I have got the code up and running but somehow gcm doesnt send me a notification for downstream messaging.

That means i am not able to connect to Gcm Ccs endpoint?

And one more thing i dont know if its connected to Ccs or not because its hosted on Openshift and i have used servlets using Jersey library to achieve it and i dont know a way to debug it.

I guess Tomcat server locally hosted would be fine but anyways i havent tried it, we are short on time anyways.

For the new version of Smack library the code completely breaks.
And i am not a pro with XMPP protocol or Smack Library either.
I just somehow got the code working with the older Smack library. I feel that my implementation is fine.

And if you want i can send you the Eclipse Java EE project for you.

The registration part for the app works fine btw.

So the Questions :-

1 -> Does GCM CCS endpoint accept only :- connection = new XMPPTCPConnection() from smack api and have stopped the connection for connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

2 -> Do Paas services like Openshift doesnt allow connection to Gcm Ccs (I have my third party app server hosted on Openshift)

3 -> Anything wrong with my approach to implement IM for android app?

Thank you! Constructive suggestions as well as criticisms is absolutely welcome.

**UPDATE**

I fixed the above problems and everything works fine. But i have stuck to a new one. I get ack and receipt packets GCM CCS sends me but i dont get any notification when i send a downstream message.

Any problem with my Broadcast Reciever? I dont think so since it looks fine.

Where can be the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you tell me how you got the Server running ? 
which version of smack  did you use ?